# Lock file when editing in server

Tags: server, remote-access, lock

Our network has 1 server and 2 clients. Our web project is stored in the server, and we edit it from both clients. When one user is editing one file, the other user shouldn't be able to edit it at the same time. How can we accomplish this? Preference is given if we can use the editor of our choice.